# AccountKit iOS (Facebook) Country Code Display

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Using v4.14.0 of AccountKit, when I present the basic

```
UIViewController<AKFViewController>
```

for phone (SMS) login using

```
viewControllerForPhoneLoginWithPhoneNumber:state:
```

I see the country codes listed as some sort of key ID instead of the actual country code (ex. "com_accountkit_country_code_US" instead of "US"). I imagine that isn't expected since the display doesn't seem to support a string that long. Is there some configuration I'm missing? I just see functionality to whitelist, blacklist, and set default country codes.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Found the bug report on Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/999399846842772/). Integrating using CocoaPods you need to download the zip of the SDK and manually grab the AccountKitStrings.bundle and add it yourself. Hopefully Facebook can fix the CocoaPods project to include this asset.